# Unable to use NancyFx Razor ViewEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nancy, owin

For more than 2 days now, I'm trying get **Razor** working as a **NancyFx ViewEngine**. I have 2 projects:

- MyApp.MainProject

  - contains OWIN, web host startup configuration, nancy bootstrapper...
- MyApp.Web

  - contains static web files & nancy modules

I installed the package `Nancy.Viewengines.Razor` and followed the instructions on this page: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine, however I'm still unable to even build the project.

First, there's always this error on every `*.cshtml` file: "Could not load file or assembly '`System.Web.Razor.Unofficial`...' although it's there and correctly referenced by the rest of the project.

Second, nearly every Razor method like `RenderSection()`, `RenderBody()` can't be resolved (*The name '...' does not exist in the current context.*)

When I remove the package `Nancy.Viewengines.Razor`, the Razor methods get recognized thanks to the toolkit *'Web Tools for Visual Studio 2012'*, but Nancy fails at loading the *.cshtml files. (Of course, Nancy doesn't know what to do with them.) If I install it again, IntelliSense breaks and I'm unable to build the project.

I followed nearly every guideline possible, registered build providers, tried with the official ASP.NET Razor package... what could I do?

Comment: Why the two projects? The Razor viewengine requires various web.config and project settings, my first reaction is to assume this has gone wrong in your two project solution. Maybe try a quick single project app to prove that it works when installed regularly.

Comment: @ChrisSainty Nope, still doesn't work. Web.config is configured in the main app where the web host starts. The reason I have 2 projects is because I currently have like 7 projects and omitted the others for brevity in the question. :)